# Magento 2 how to add eav attribute for store information?

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes

How can I add an eav attribute for store? I practically need to add a post code but storeview scope. The problem is that the post code for store information has website scope.

I have addedd eav attributes before, but what would be the ENTITY and how can I change to storeview scope?

Something like this:

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            /**
            * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
            */
            
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Store\Model\???::ENTITY,
                'is_featured',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'Post Code',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => ''
                ]
            );
```

This is the place where I need to add it.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Would you add the new filed in store information ,right ?

Answer (score 1):

Store information is not an EAV attribute so you will have to take a different approach.

It is a system config value stored in the core_config_data table, these values are configured using /etc/adminhtml/system.xml.

Postcode is defined in the Magento_Backend module. To change the scope of this variable you will have to override it and change the scope for postcode that is set in:

/vendor/magento/module-backend/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

I would recommend creating your own module with these files:

app/code/StackExchange/StoreInformation/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="general">
            <group id="store_information">
                <field id="postcode" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>ZIP/Postal Code - Override</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/StoreInformation/etc/module.xml
(the sequence is important here)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_StoreInformation" setup_version="0.1.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

app/code/StackExchange/StoreInformation/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_StoreInformation',
    __DIR__
);
```

Enable the module from cli
Run setup:upgrade

You will then have the attribute in the correct scope as expected:

[image]